# Show footnotes on odd pages only

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, conditionals, double-sided

I'm writing my thesis using the `scrbook`-class. Is it possible to display footnotes only on the odd (right) pages?

This should mean that `\footnote{something}` should be collected on even pages and displayed on the next page (of course followed by the footnotes from this page).

I've seen this behavior in a few textbooks and thought it was quite nice, but don't know how to achieve this style.

P.S.: Of course one has to violate this approach when a chapter ends on an even page.

MWE (does not do what I want):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]\footnote{First footnote}
\blindtext[2]\footnote{Second footnote}
\blindtext[2]\footnote{Third footnote}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Should look like:
[image]

Comment: An MWE would be useful, you should know that ;) And can I ask why would you like that?

Comment: First thought that a MWE wouldn't be that helpful, as I don't know how to achieve what I'm asking. I expected that maybe someone comes up: Hey, you just need to enable the option `someoption` from `somepackage`. Nevertheless, I have added a MWE now and also two pictures (second one is photomanipulated). I think that it gives a nicer output if there are less footnote-rules, while it does not limit the readability as all footnotes you might need are always visible.

Comment: I don't know what type of work you typeset and in what field, but IMHO it is a bad style to have many footnotes. You either want to say it (and then it goes in the text) or you do not (and then it should be omitted).

Comment: My work is in the field of physics. I don't have to many footnotes, but sometimes they are needed, e.g. to point out a requirement for the validity of an equation. As a physicist you know those requirements and assume anyway that these requirements are all met. The thing is here that I found that the text gets quite boring sometimes when giving them all inside the text. Nevertheless, they have to be mentioned somewhere.

Comment: @DL6ER I've modified my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following solution uses the `\label`-`\ref` system to record a footnote and retrieve it, possibly on the current page, or possibly `\afterpage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}% http://ctan.org/pkg/KOMA-script
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{afterpage,etoolbox,refcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{afterpage,etoolbox,refcount}
\patchcmd{\footnotemark}{\stepcounter}{\refstepcounter}{}{}% Update \footnotemark to allow \label-\ref
\let\oldfootnote\footnote% Store \footnote in \oldfootnote
\let\oldfootnotetext\footnotetext% Store \footnotetext in \oldfootnotetext
\newcounter{fntext}% Footnote text counter (for correct sequential retrieval of footnote text
\renewcommand{\footnotetext}{\stepcounter{fntext}\oldfootnotetext}
\renewcommand{\footnote}{\evenfootnote}
\newcommand{\evenfootnote}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\footnotemark\label{evenfn-\thefootnote}% Set footnote mark
  \ifodd\getpagerefnumber{evenfn-\thefootnote}\relax% Page is odd
    \def\whichpage{\afterpage}% Footnote text on next page
  \else
    \def\whichpage{\relax}% Footnote text on current page
  \fi%
  \whichpage{\footnotetext[\getrefnumber{evenfn-\thefntext}]{#1}}% Set footnote text
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{First footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Second footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Third footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Fourth footnote}
\lipsum*[1]\evenfootnote{Mystery footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Fifth footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Sixth footnote}

\end{document}
```

[`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) provides expandable macros that extracts page references, used in testing whether the current page is odd or not.

Comment: It seems to work fine (unlike mine...) also when there is an even page with no footnotes. +1(00) ;-)

Comment: By the way: KOMA-Script provides `\ifthispageodd{<true>}{<false>}` It would allow a definition without `refcount`

Answer (score 6):

This one can be a solution (seeing the image, I'm assuming you want footnotes in even pages, not in odd ones).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi,etoolbox}

\newcounter{newfoot}
\patchcmd{\footnotetext}{\thempfn}{\thenewfoot}{}{}

\newcommand{\evenfootnote}[1]{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \footnotemark%
    \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
      \stepcounter{newfoot}\footnotetext{#1}%
    }%
  \else%
    \stepcounter{newfoot}\footnote{#1}%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{First footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Second footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Third footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Fourth footnote}
\lipsum*[1]\evenfootnote{Mystery footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Fifth footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Sixth footnote}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

We use the trick to define a new counter `newfoot` and let `\footnotetext` use this one:

```
\newcounter{newfoot}
\patchcmd{\footnotetext}{\thempfn}{\thenewfoot}{}{}
```

When we are in an odd page, only the footnote mark is printed, while the footnote text is printed in the next page exploiting the command `\AtBeginShipoutNext` provided by the package [`atbegshi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi).

When we are in an even page, the usual command `\footnote` is used.

So we define a new command `\evenfootnote` which takes care of the above:

```
\newcommand{\evenfootnote}[1]{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \footnotemark%
    \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
      \stepcounter{newfoot}\footnotetext{#1}%
    }%
  \else%
    \stepcounter{newfoot}\footnote{#1}%
  \fi%
}
```

Note that the new counter `newfoot` is incremented each time a footnote is printed.

Comment: This still lacks proper page-number checking, since the output of pages happens asynchronously. For example, use the document `\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{First footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Second footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Third footnote}
\lipsum[1-3]\evenfootnote{Fourth footnote}
\lipsum*[1]\evenfootnote{Mystery footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Fifth footnote}
\lipsum[1-2]\evenfootnote{Sixth footnote}` which prints a footnote on page 3 (non-even/odd).

Comment: Perhaps the code for `\strictpagecheck` from `changepage.sty` could be adapted to this purpose.

Comment: @Werner now it seems to work fine...

Comment: @jon thanks for the suggestion. I've found a simpler way.